# How to convert a String to Time in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, time

When I try to convert a string to time it doesn't work with the following code and I can't understand why could someone help me please ?

```py
pd.to_datetime(movie_df['duration'], format='%M min')
```

I get this error :

> ValueError: time data '93 min' does not match format '%M min' (match)

Answer (score 1):

You could remove `min` in `duration` first, then convert it to [pandas.TimedeltaIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.TimedeltaIndex.html)

```py
movie_df['duration'] = movie_df['duration'].str.split(' ').str[0].astype(int)

movie_df['duration'] = pd.TimedeltaIndex(movie_df['duration'], unit='m').to_pytimedelta().astype(str)
```

```
print(movie_df)

  duration
0  1:33:00
1  1:42:00
```

Thanks for [MrFuppes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10197418/mrfuppes) suggestion, you can use [pandas.to_timedelta()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html).

```py
movie_df['duration'] = movie_df['duration'].str.split(' ').str[0].astype(int)
movie_df['duration'] = pd.to_timedelta(movie_df['duration'], unit='m').astype(str)
```

```
# print(movie_df)

          duration
0  0 days 01:33:00
1  0 days 01:42:00
```

Comment: Why not simply parse with `pd.to_timedelta`?

Answer (score 1):

`%M` refers to "minutes" of the hour. (between 0 to 60 (exclusive)).

Further, "X min" is when forcefully converted to a`datetime` object will most likely lose its semantics.

```py
>>> datetime.strptime('45 min', "%M min")
datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 45)
```

In the above example, even when the conversion does work, it's most likely not what you want (00:45 of 1st Jan 1900).

Looks like you are more dealing with durations and should not be using `to_datetime` function.
Check out [time-deltas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timedeltas.html), (and incidentally as @MrFuppens also points out,`to_timedelta` function)

Answer (score 0):

try to use this function: strptime ()
[https://thispointer.com/python-string-to-datetime-or-date-object/#:~:text=Convert%20string%20to%20time%20object%20in%20Python%20In,overview%20of%20this%20function.%20Syntax%20of%20datetime.strptime%20%28%29](https://thispointer.com/python-string-to-datetime-or-date-object/#:%7E:text=Convert%20string%20to%20time%20object%20in%20Python%20In,overview%20of%20this%20function.%20Syntax%20of%20datetime.strptime%20%28%29)

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged because links can break over time and render the answer useless.  Please provide a summary of the solution here and why your answer may be preferable over the other answers already provided.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because the function does not know how to convert 93 min , because min should be < 60. So You can convert the duration to hours:min format.
Eg: convert the 90 min to h:min string and run your time conversion on that.

```
df['duration'].apply(lambda x: str(int(x.split()[0])//60) +":"+ str(int(x.split()[0])%60)) 
pd.to_datetime(movie_df['duration'], format='%H:%M')
```